# Radio buttons rendered as bootstrap data-toggle=buttons, MVC validation fails

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I am working on a MVC5 app with its default validation. A Required property on a model is rendered as radio buttons in a from. Validation works fine so far. If a radio button is not selected, a validation message shows up fine that a value has not been selected. These options are a part of List in a model, and as many as 10 group of radio buttons are rendered on the page.

I changed these radio buttons using bootstrap's data-toggle=buttons. The buttons are displayed fine. However if i choose a button now, the underlying radio button does not get the click. Fine, i wrote some jquery to propagte the click to the underlying radio button. Here arises the problem. Even though the radio button gets a checked="checked" now, mvc validation still prints the validation message that a value has not been selected.

The corresponding html for one group in the view is as follows:

```
<div class="UserRbAnswer btn-group margin" data-toggle="buttons">    
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input class="myRadioButton valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OptionChoiceId must be a number." data-val-required="Please select a status." id="QuestionResponseList_1__OptionChoiceId" name="QuestionResponseList[1].OptionChoiceId" type="radio" value="1">
    Acceptable
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input class="myRadioButton valid" id="QuestionResponseList_1__OptionChoiceId" name="QuestionResponseList[1].OptionChoiceId" type="radio" value="2">
    Not Acceptable
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input class="myRadioButton valid" id="QuestionResponseList_1__OptionChoiceId" name="QuestionResponseList[1].OptionChoiceId" type="radio" value="3" checked="checked">
    Not Applicable
</label>
<div><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="QuestionResponseList[1].OptionChoiceId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
```

You will notice that the third option has attribute checked added. The jquery i wrote to propagate to the radio button is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.UserRbAnswer .btn').click(function () {
        $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

How do I go about it that MVC validation recognises that a radio button has been selected now and it should not mark this as an error?

I do not have enough reputation at the moment to post image of radio buttons here, but if i need be, i can host it somewhere.

There is also another quirk. I have a drop down at the top of the page that allows me to select a value for all of my radio buttons on the page. If i select a value from this drop down, MVC validation recognises that a radio button has been selected.

Html for this drop down:

```
<select class="OptionSelect">
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">Acceptable</option>
<option value="2">Not Acceptable</option>
<option value="3">Not Applicabale</option>
</select>
```

The corresponding jquery:

```
   $('.OptionSelect').change(function () {            
        var val = this.value;
        //mark all radio buttons as unchecked
        $('.UserRbAnswer :radio').attr('checked', false);
        //select the radio buttons that match
        $('.UserRbAnswer :radio[value=' + val + ']').attr('checked', 'checked')
        //add active class to the labels
        $('[id^="QuestionResponseList_"]').each(function () {
            $(this).parent('label').removeClass('active');
            if (this.checked) $(this).parent('label').addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

The radio button has the following css:

```
[data-toggle=buttons]>.btn>input[type=radio]    
{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
```

The label on top has a z-index of +2, so the radio button is not displayed. Validation does bind to it, but when i add checked to radio button through jquery and submit the form, validation displays the error that a button has not been selected.

Please provide some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Unobtrusive validation is not performed on hidden elements by default. If you inspect the `jquery.validate.js` file you will see that the default settings include `ignore: ":hidden"`. You could override this using

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: [] // or ignore: "" depending on the jquery version
});
```

or (in document.ready)

```
$('form').validate({
  ignore: []
});
```

Your script to set the state of the radio buttons is not necessary as clicking on the label (styled as button) will toggle the state of the radio button anyway. [Refer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JfMp/435/)

Note: Its a little unclear why you have 4 possible values but are only rendering 3 options so I'm not sure what your trying to achieve with this design

Comment: Adding this trigger, just keeps calling this click function itself, the click gets propagted to the label. Doesnt help. And yes, um talking about unobtrusive client validation

Comment: Then something does not make sense here. The html you generated works fine without the script, so I assume bootstrap's `data-toggle=buttons` must prevent the label triggering the click (why else would you need the script?). And if you do not contain the radio button within the label (use the `for` attribute instead) then it would not be a problem

Comment: Have you styled the radio buttons as hidden?

Comment: Yes they r hidden, bootstrap hides these radio buttons. An example of these radio buttons can be found at this bootstrap link, [link]http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Comment: OK, now it makes sense. I'll change answer to explain whats happening.

Comment: Hey, thank you Stephen for taking the time out to help.
I edited my question, the buttons are not hidden, they have a negative z-index, while the label has a higher z-index. Validation does bind to it. The problem is, it does not recognize the radio button as checked, and displays the error message that a required value has not been selected.

Comment: I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JfMp/436/) using your css. As you can see there is no need for `$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');` to set the value, so there must be some other issue (I don't use bootstrap so not sure).

Comment: Yes, i am still looking for the issue, thanks for your help stephen :)